# Google maps v3 street view pegmen position

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

How would I get street view pegmen offset position in div.
I need it for placing infobox/tooltip beside pegmen.
Is there any API call for creating infobox relative to pegmen or gettin his offset?
Position of pegmen is changing according to maps control (if google maps canvas is smaller then 350px mini controls are implemented in it)

Comment: Why the f..ck I get minus reputation on this totally legal question. Google doesn't offer any api to add additional info on pegmen icon. I'm long time in UX development and you can't believe what kind of users exist out there. So please don't be rude and discredit this question, or at least response with good argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var svpLatLon = map.getStreetView().getPosition();
var dummy = new google.maps.OverlayView();
var proj = dummy.getProjection();
var pixel = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(svpLatLon);
```

Then you can read

```
var x = pixel.x;
var y = pixel.y;
```